# Does specifying a file in a CSP directive prevent other files from that domain being loaded?

Tags: content-security-policy, script-src

If I have the following `script-src` directive:

`script-src: https://example.com/scripts/file.js;`

Is it possible for any of the following scripts to be loaded?

1. `https://example.com/file.js`
2. `https://example.com/assets/file.js`
3. `https://example.com/scripts/different-file.js`

Does this apply to all browsers and CSP v2 / CSP v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specifications for [CSP v2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-CSP2-20161215/#host_source)  and [CSP v3](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#match-url-to-source-expression), this can be used in both v2 and v3. I would expect browsers to support it as major browsers have supported v2 for years. None of the example scripts should be loaded with the given CSP.